# modify value on a table with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with mssql. I dont know anything from mssql query, but I know some programing.

I have 2 tables, *TableA* and *TableB* each one has 2 columns 
ColumnA1, ColumnA2, ColumnB1 and ColumnB2

Something like this

```
create table DB.dbo.TableA
(ColumnA1 varchar(10),
ColumnA2 int)
create table DB.dbo.TableB
(ColumnB1 varchar(10),
ColumnB2 int)
```

And I need to check if exist a row in TableA where ColumnA2>0
if so, then,
IF any of those possible rows also exists in ColumnB1,
update ColumnB2=ColumnB2+ColumnA2 and set ColumnA2=0
ELSE
insert a new row in TableB with ColumnB1=ColumnA1 and ColumnB2=ColumnA1 and set ColumnA2=0

I don't even know where to start, I tryed to explain it the best way I could.

EDIT:
Before the script

```
TableA:  
ColumnA1    ColumnA2  
John        0  
Sam         1  
Mark        1  


TableB:  
ColumnB1    ColumnB2  
Sam         5
```

After the script should be something like this:

```
TableA:  
ColumnA1    ColumnA2  
John        0  
Sam         0  
Mark        0  

TableB:  
ColumnB1    ColumnB2  
Sam         6  
Mark        1
```

Comment: Are the 2 tables related to each other?

Comment: both are on the same database, i dont know if its possible, but modifying one wont modify the other

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your requirement properly but the below code using `Merge` will atleast help you in the right direction .

```
    MERGE TableB B
    USING TableA A
   ON A.ColumnA1 = B.ColumnB1        //The columns which related to both the tables
   WHEN MATCHED AND
   A.ColumnA2>0 THEN
   UPDATE
   SET B.ColumnB2 = B.ColumnB2 + A.ColumnA2
   when not matched by target Then 
   Insert(ColumnB1,ColumnB2) 
   values (A.ColumnA1,A.ColumnB2)
   Output A.ColumnA1 into @t;

   Update TableA
   Set ColumnA2=0
   WHERE ColumnA1 in (SELECT ColumnA1
                 FROM @t);
```

Comment: most of the time ColumnA2 will be 0, how would it be if i wanna check first if ColumnA2>0 and then check if ColumnA1 exists in ColumnB1

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MERGE` syntax

```
 merge TableB 
 using 
    (select * from tablea where ColumnA2>0) source 
    ON source.ColumnA1 = tableb.ColumnB1      
 when matched then
 update 
    set tableb.ColumnB2 = tableb.ColumnB2 + source.ColumnA2 
 when not matched by target Then  
    insert(ColumnB1,ColumnB2)  
    values (source.ColumnA1,source.ColumnA2)
```